# The state in React Context does not change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have been practicing with React Context, but I have a problem with storing a user in my general state, the problem is that I have to click the save button twice to save the state in my context, with the first click I only see that the state is as an empty object and with the second click the state is saved (the name and password), this is the code I have. This would be the context of my application:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const UserContext = createContext()
export default UserContext
```

this would be my types file:

```
export const LOGIN= 'LOGIN'
```

this is my UserState file:

```
import { useReducer } from "react"
import UserReducer from './UserReducer'
import UserContext from "./UserContex"

const UserState = ({ children }) => {
    const initialState = {
        usernew: {}
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(UserReducer, initialState)

    const login = (userLogin) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN',
            payload: userLogin
        })
        window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(state.usernew))
        const data = window.localStorage.getItem('user')
        console.log(data)
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider
            value={{
                usernew: state.usernew,
                login,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default UserState
```

UserReducer file:

```
import {LOGIN} from "../types";

export default (state, action) => {
    const { payload, type } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case LOGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                usernew: payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

and this would be my component where I am changing the context:

```
import { Box, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { Input } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import UserContext from '../context/User/UserContex'

const Login = () => {

    const { login, usernew} = useContext(UserContext)

    const [fields, setFields] = useState({
        name: '',
        password: ''
    })

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;

        setFields({
            ...fields,
            [name]: value
        })
    }
    return (
        <Box w='80%' p={4}>
            <Input
                placeholder='Name'
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="name"
                value={fields.name}
            />
            <Input
                placeholder='Password'
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="password"
                value={fields.password}
            />
            <Button bg="teal" color="#fff" onClick={() => login(fields)}>Submit</Button>
            {usernew ?
                <div>
                    <h2>Usuario con {usernew.name} - {usernew.password}</h2>
                </div>
                :
                <div>
                    <h1>Sin usuario</h1>
                </div>
            }

        </Box>

    )
}

export default Login
```

I checked all the code but I can't find the error, that's why I'm showing all the code I have. Thank you for your attention

Comment: Where are you seeing it not update? What are you looking at? What are you doing to verify/validate the state in the context isn't updating? I see no overt issues with the code so I suspect you might be trying to console log the state right after dispatching an action to update it. Remember that React state updates are asynchronously processed and not immediate.

Comment: Also as a side note, if you're using consts for your action type in the reducer, you should import and use the same consts when dispatching.

Comment: Thank you very much, and about what you said, I made a console.log to the action and the result is the type"Login" and the dispatch "password, name" and I can see that it receives the data from the inputs, but at the time of printing the states shows me an empty object, I have to press the button twice to save the data.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/the-state-in-react-context-does-not-change-ordbs) and it updates with first click when submitting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but do you have any idea why it works normally in codesandox and not in my original project?

Comment: @YCrhis Unfortunately no. It's pretty trivial code so I wouldn't expect it to run differently in a CSB versus locally. Can you try creating a codesandbox of your own with a more representative example of your app code to see if there's something else in your UI jacking with the above code?

Comment: yes it could be, thank you for your help.